# Calculate the volume of the solid [question b]

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, volume

How to solve the below problem in question **(b)**?

***a) Calculate the area of the region enclosed by the lines y = x, x = 0 and y + x = 2, and is above the plane xy. 
 b) Calculate the volume of the solid where it is enclosed from the region of (a) in the plane xy and the surface z = x^2 + y^2***

Here is my solution:

[image]

Please tell my if i solve it correct.

Comment: @SarGe The question b it is correct?

Comment: I hope you got the answer. :-)

Comment: @SarGe What do you mean?

Comment: @Or Shahar's answer.

Comment: @SarGe Ah yeap!

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is correct.

If Im right, the
second answer is $\frac{4}{3}$. You did  all the calculus right, but you have a calculation mistake at the end.

The picture from "Symbolab"
[image]

Comment: No problem for the calculation mistake. I care for the calculus and if the integrals and the integration edges it is okay?

Comment: Yes, the integration is right.

Comment: @OrShahar, Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).